# Excel VBA adding rows based on criteria, stopping failure when no criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

All -

This macro below adds all rows containing a specific criteria to another worksheet in the workbook.

My only problem is if there are not any rows that contain the criteria it fails.  Is there a way to stop it from failing and just add nothing in the instance that no criteria is found?

```
Sub Test()

Dim rData As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
   .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="Yes"
   With .AutoFilter.Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rData Is Nothing Then
            Intersect(rData, .Range("A:U")).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        End If
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to see if the count of "Yes" in that column is greater than 0. If 0, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try handling the error. Add `On Error GoTo <Label>` statement just after the subroutine starts and provide an empty Labelled block at the end of the subroutine. You can alter the error handling behaviour to make it more meaningful. You can get more information about `On Error` statements here. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement#:~:text=On%20Error%20GoTo%200%20disables,when%20a%20procedure%20is%20exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement#:%7E:text=On%20Error%20GoTo%200%20disables,when%20a%20procedure%20is%20exited).

The code will look something like this.

```
Sub Test()
On Error GoTo END_OF_EXECUTION
    Dim rData As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="Yes"
        With .AutoFilter.Range
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rData Is Nothing Then
                Intersect(rData, .Range("A:U")).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
END_OF_EXECUTION:
    MsgBox("No row found", , "Error")
End Sub
```

Comment: Any thoughts on why when I add in these lines it doesn't actually paste the data?  It doesn't throw an error but it doesn't paste the data.  If I comment out "On Error Goto.." and "End of Execution  MsgBox " it pastes the data which with no problem like my original code.  Again, my original code only pastes the data without error IF there is filtered criteria that matches.  With your code, it looks like no errors are prompted, but no data is pasted either.  Is it just the positioning of it or something?

Comment: Can you retry commenting out `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` these two lines.